# JavaScript not Validating

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, validation, alert

What is wrong with this code?

The webpage is importing this external JavaScript however, on wrong input by user, alert message box is not displayed.

**page.jsp:**

```
   <form name="reg-form" action="ServletName" 
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST"> 
<table>
     <tr>
    <td>
        <input name="organization" type="text" required>
    </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
            </td>
     </tr> 
  </table>
 </form>
```

**val.js:**

```
function validateForm() 
{
var result=true;
var message="";

var orgnization=document.forms["reg-form"]["organization"].value;
if(orgnization.length<3)
{
    message+="\nName of Organization cannot be less than 3 characters long";
    result=false;
}
if(!result)
{
    alert(message);
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fye8wqku/ Look in the JavaScript error console and tell what errors you see there if any.

Comment: @Juhana I am coding in NetBeans, how do i find JavaScript error console?

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: when you say "on wrong input by user" do you mean if the box is empty? or any wrong(="","a","ab")  input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 function validateForm() 
 {
 var result=true;
 var message="";

 var orgnization=document.getElementsByName["organization"][0].value;
 if(orgnization.length<3)
 {
   message +="\n Name of Organization cannot be less than 3 characters long";
   result=false;
 }
 if(!result)
 {
   alert(message);
 }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Why down vote.. Please specify the reason? I want to know..what's wrong here?